# XMLHttpRequest does not exist on type Window

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a small async library for my projects. I decided to code it in TypeScript, but my compiler is throwing me an error that `'XMLHttpRequest' does not exist on type 'Window'`, as the title says.

What I wanted to achieve is creation of ActiveXObject if window has no XMLHttprequest.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

It's not really necessary for me to include it, but I'm wondering why is that?

---

IDE I'm using is VS Code (which also shows me the error) and I'm compiling with `gulp-tsify`

Comment: You'll have to go back a long way to find a browser that doesn't natively support XHR.

Comment: Of course, I understand that, but I was just curious. I'm actually making it not only for me, but also for my friend and I'm not sure of the versions of the browsers they're using. I saw the win XP on one of their machines, so it's better to be prepared for that :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((<any>window).XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

The thing is that `Typescript` has a type for every object where it defines the properties of that type, sometimes there are missing properties (or properties that are added dynamically later) from those definitions, if you cast it to type `any` then it will deal with it as an anonymous type.